# A problem on limits and Leibniz rule

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

> [image]

The answers are A, B and C. I got B and C. I just applied Leibniz rule and got 
$
f'(x)-f(x)=c
$
and $f''(x)-f(x)=c$.

But how do I get A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should have said $\displaystyle f'(x) = f(x) + \int_{-10}^{10} f(u) \, du $ rather than $\displaystyle f'(x) = f(x) + \int_{-10}^{10} f(x) \, dx$ but in this case the problem of using the same letter, $x,$ for two different things does not seem as bad as it would normally be because in a sense it has complete its duty in the expression $f'(x) = f(x) + \cdots$ before you get to the integral. So we have
$$
f'(x) = f(x) + \int_{-10}^{10} f(u) \, du.
$$
A crucial point is that the integral is a "constant," which in this case means it does not change as $x$ changes. So you have
$$
f'(x) = f(x) + \text{a constant.}
$$
What number the constant is depends on which function $f$ is.

You therefore have $f'(x) - f(x) = \text{some constant},$ but whether it could be just any number at all, consistently with the given information, takes some work to discover.

If option (A) is right, it will take some work to show it.

Let's see what else we can find out about this function:
\begin{align}
& \frac {df}{dx} = f + C. \\[10pt]
& \frac{df}{f+C} = dx. \\[10pt]
& \int \frac{df}{f+C} = \int dx. \\[10pt]
& \log|f+C| = x + B \qquad \text{(where $B$ is some other constant)}. \\[10pt]
& f+C = e^x e^B = \big( e^x \times \text{a positive constant}\big). \\[10pt]
& f+C = Ae^x \quad \text{(where $A$ is a constant that need not be positive)}. \\[10pt]
& f(x) = Ae^x - C = Ae^x - \int_{-10}^{10} f(u) \,du = Ae^x - \int_{-10}^{10} (Ae^u-C)\,du. \\[10pt]
& C = \int_{-10}^{10} (Ae^u-C)\,du = \int_{-10}^{10} Ae^u \,du - 20C. \\[10pt]
& 21C = \int_{-10}^{10} Ae^u \, du = A(e^{10} - e^{-10}). \\[10pt]
& f(x) = Ae^x - \frac{A}{21(e^{10} - e^{-10})}
\end{align}
and $A$ could be any number at all.

Note that as $x\to-\infty$, we have $e^x\to 0,$ so this whole thing goes to $0$ only if $A=0.$ In that case $f(x) = 0$ for all values of $x,$ and in that case $f'=f.$

I had thought at first this would be a routine freshman calculus exercise. The part about separation of variables is often not taught in first-year calculus, but that can be overcome by talking about the chain rule. But this whole thing requires more skill than what is usually expect of freshmen, even though all this can be done with no more knowledge than what is taught at that level.

As for using the letter $x$ for two different things, for several reasons I think that's a bad idea.

Comment: Exactly, but this question is from a very reputed exam so I don't think there is much scope for error. Any proof would be appreciated

Comment: @Winther : Perhaps I was mistaken about that. I'll alter the answer a bit.

Comment: ok, For the moment this answer is a work in progress. I had thought at first it would be a routine freshman calculus exercise. Stand by.....

Comment: If f'(x)-f(x)=c , e^-x f'(x) - f(x)e^-x=e^-x(c). So f(x)= -C+Be^x now the limit shows that C=0 hence we can say that f'(x)=f(x)?

Comment: @Winther: Thank you for the answer!